# Is this patent still legally protected?

Tags: design-patent, design

In reference to the patent: [US3166129](https://www.google.com/patents/US3166129)

Answer (score 0):

This is a utility patent, not a design patent. Because it was issued well before 1995, its term is 17 years from the issue date so it should have expired on Jan 19, 1982.

Patent terms are easily researched and have been answered multiple times on this site. Please see this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent).